How do I know which keyboard layout I am currently using?
I've tried setxkbmap -query and this is what I get:
rules:       evdev
model:       pc105
layout:      br,br
variant:        ,

Which suggests I am using the br keyboard  (although I have no idea why it appears twice as br,br). But I checked the  br text file in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ and one of the keys is described as such:
 key <AD04> { [            h,               H,            paragraph,        paragraph ] };

Suggesting that, if I were to type altgr + h, I would get the paragraph symbol §, which doesn't happen. Instead, I get the ħ symbol, which is nowhere to be found in the br file. The combination I actually have to type in order to get the paragraph symbol "§" is altgr+shift+s, which also shouldn't happen as the br file specifies the following:
key <AC08> { [            s,               S,               ssharp,            U1E9E ] };

altgr+shift+s should yield the U1E9E UniCode character, which is ẞ, instead of §.
I am trying to make a custom keyboard layout to add the following symbols to my keyboard: —, –, å e  Å.  I'm not tech savvy and I managed to change my keyboard layout when I used Windows because there were nice programs with user-friendly GUI to create personalized keyboard layouts, but with Linux it has been much difficult to do so, as there are obviously some steps along the way which I have no clue as to how they work.

Is that the only line for AD04 in the file?
